# Replace segue creating new instance

Tags: ios5, uisplitviewcontroller, segue

I've run into a problem with a SplitViewController app. When I select a row from the table in the master view I'm replacing the detail view with a replace segue. The problem is each time this happens it creates a new instance/reloads the detail view controller. Is there any way I can have it so it will replace the detail view with the previous instance if it has already been instantiated. I'd like the state for the detail views to be remembered, such as input into textfields.

Comment: I'm just starting to work with the iPad storyboard (including split view controllers), but isn't there a Push segue you can use instead of the replace?  Or does the framework not allow Push in this case?  This works well on the iPhone idiom.

Comment: I tried push but decided I didn't want the back navigation. I remember that also created a new instance each time. I've kind of solved it by declaring each detail ViewController as a property on the master ViewController and instantiating them on the first segue. Then I don't call performSegue and instead push/pop manually the instances onto the detail view.

Comment: I would also like to know how to use replace segues. What is the difference between a replace segue and a push segue? If the replaced view controller stays in memory, then how can it be restored?

Comment: I found a way of doing what I wanted. Hide the navigation bar and use a custom segue that pushes the view controller without animation. Then pop back to the root whenever changing the detail view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cannot be done. A segue will always instantiate a view controller

Answer (score 1):

I use the replace segue, but in the MasterVC I implement

```
-(BOOL)shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender:(id)sender {

    if ([identifier isEqualToString:@"showCalculatorViewController"]) {

        if (self.splitViewController) {

            NSObject *currentDetail = [self.splitViewController.viewControllers lastObject];

            if ([currentDetail isKindOfClass:[RootCalcViewController class]]) {

....
```

Then I fill in the new properties of the existing VC, and return NO.

But I do not have a UINAvigationController as my initial Detail View Controller,  since I handle the navigation from the masterVCs.

Also, in AppDelegate, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions the correct detail VC needs to be set up.  The generated code assumes that it is a UINavigationController.  Similarly in the generated MasterViewController, viewDidLoad.  This will save you some app crashes if you replace the detail UINAvigationController.

When I load different view controllers, I let the "Replace segues" replace them.

Answer (score 0):

Or - you could just make your DetailController implement Singleton patter and forward any calls to +new, +alloc or the like to your singleton method.