# UISplitView: Why are there multiple DetailController-Instances? (new one on each segue)

Tags: ios, iphone, uikit, uisplitviewcontroller, master-detail

I've noticed that in a Master-Detail `UISplitView` *iPhone* app, I dont have *one single* instance of my `DetailController` and getting that reused by setting new content, instead it seems that on each segue/everytime I navigate to the Detail View, a new instance of `DetailController` gets created by the segue and has to be filled with content?

Why is that? Through debugging I can see that there is at least one `DetailController` instance staying alive all the time but not used on iPhone, and everytime I segue from Master to Detail, a new instance is created.

I would like to just use one instance to be more efficient (memory,speed) ... Is there some easy switch to change this behaviour, or would I have to implement Singleton in my `DetailController` to prevent additional instances from being created?

By the way, I am using a new master-detail-project with apple-code.

Answer (score 0):

After further search, found this possible workaround (possible alternative instead of using singleton):
[Replace segue creating new instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9994876/replace-segue-creating-new-instance/33809362#33809362)

Basically it says to stop the segue from happening by returning NO in -shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:sender:, after setting the new content in the old instance. Might work on iPad, but on iphone the segue animation is needed to bring the detail view up.

Comment: After further research, I was not able to implement a singleton into a subclass of UIViewController _and_ forward calls from init to my sharedInstance() -> would be doable in ObjC, but doesnt work for me in swift ...?