# Swift: How to override/forward init call to my singleton initilializer?

Tags: ios, swift, inheritance, singleton

I found out that a singleton in swift is easy (credits go to krakendev.io):

```
class TheOneAndOnlyKraken {
    static let sharedInstance = TheOneAndOnlyKraken()
    private init() {} //This prevents others from using the default '()' initializer for this class.
}
```

But I was not able to do this with a subclass and required designated initializers in the superclass. When I try to define all designated initializers private, compiler say that required init method from super must be accessible.

How can I make a subclass (for ex. from UIViewController) to be a singleton with exactly one instance and forward all init-calls to my singleton instance?? I cannot modify self in my init, too('self is immutable').

Comment: You can't. A singleton UIViewController doesn't make a lot of sense anyway.

Comment: Yeap, what Paul said, but perhaps setting default values for a subclass of UIViewContriller and then forcing all your viewcontrollers in app to be of type class your CusatomUIViewController, then you will probagly get the same results.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Why doesnt it make sense, @Paulw11? In a Master-Detail view, I want my Detail view to stay the same over different segues forth-and-back, just the content to be replaced (see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33806621/uisplitview-why-are-there-multiple-detailcontroller-instances-new-one-on-each/33809620#33809620)

Comment: believe or not, singletons are a smart way to do something stupid. i don't argue against singleton pattern at all, sometime it has a sense, or better say, we have to use it (aka UIApplication). to share one instance of detail view controller seem for me as bad idea too ...  the trouble with apple master-detail demo is how it works the data model, not the UI self.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I am interested in the reason why my DetailViewController needs a new isntance all the time, even if I am only going back-and-forth in UISplitView. I can understand that "when apple made it like that, its the right way", but I would like to know why.

Comment: DetailViewController doesn't need to be a new instance every time.  It is entirely up to how you write your code.  I don't have enough information on how your app navigation is organised, but you basically just hold a reference to your detail view controller in your master view controller and send it messages when you want its content to change.  You don't need a singleton to do this.

Comment: I cant follow what you say - `UIViewController` and the `UINavigationController` _do_ indeed create a new instance of the `Detail View Controller` on iPhone _and_ iPad, too. This happens when I click on a tableview item in the master controller. You can reproduce with debugging by creating a new apple-master-detail-project.